# Check if a field is set from an array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

in my current rails project I want to load a number of 'sources', depending on the configured research methods. For a  research the user configures what methods he want's to use, this information is available in the controller as an array of strings. On the other side there are sources that are configured by the admins, for each source we say for which researches the source is usefull.

These are the sources:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: sources
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  title          :string(255)
#  url            :string(255)
#  WebSearch      :boolean
#  DatabaseSearch :boolean
#  LibrarySearch  :boolean
#  Interview      :boolean

@sources = Source.all
```

For the boolean fields there exist corresponding models with exactly that name. In the controller I read the activated methods in that way:

```
@categories << @question.research_categories.detect{|c| c == params[:type]}

=> @categories = ["WebSearch", "Interview"]
```

What I want to do is something like "Source.where(@categories = ?)" and get only the sources with the names contained in the @categories array.

Comment: is it going to be a OR condition? meaning is it okay if one of the category has a true value in the column?

Comment: good point by @emaillenin, my answer would have to be slightly different if it is mandatory that the columns not included in `@category` have to be false.

Comment: is the number of categories going to increase in future or it will be always 4?

Comment: @emaillenin: At the moment (and since several month) there are only these four categories. I will refactor to a more dynamic approach when there should come more categories in furure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the give structure (hope I understand it right) what you want to do is generate a search based on the names.

For your example you would need as a result to get

```
.where(WebSearch: true, Interview: true)
```

from

```
@categories = ["WebSearch", "Interview"]
```

so all you need to do is map the array into such a hash:

```
Hash[@categories.map{|v|[v, true]}]
```

best would be to combine that with a `scope`.

```
class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_categories, ->(categories) { where(Hash[categories.map{|v|[v, true]}]) }
end
```

should work (not tested) and allow you to write:

```
Source.with_categories(@categories)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Source.joins(:research_categories)
      .where("research_categories.name in (:names)", names: @categories)
```